# Отслеживать обращение к классу

Tags: c#

У меня есть класс - api для работы с sql, иногда проседает интернет, и приходится повышать время прерывания с 50 мс до 75-90. Я хочу сделать, так чтобы при 20 любых успешных вызовов методов из этого класса возвращалось время обратно до 50 mc. Методов 70, обращений из кода более 350.

Возможно ли отслеживать обращение к моему классу `ApiData` или как мне поступить?

Comment: только если в каждом методе добавлять счетчик

Comment: Скорее всего можно добавить функционал с помощью PostSharp

Comment: @АндрейNOP, либо любой другой AOP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я когда-то делал логгирование с помощью AOP
Например. У вас есть класс, который нужно отcелживать.
Помечаете его атрибутом. В моем случае это `HelloWorld`

```
[HelloWorld]
public class SomeService1 : MarshalByRefObject
{
    public void Method1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("SomeService1.Method1");
    }
}
```

Далее определяем сам атрибут и обработчик

```
public sealed class HelloWorldAttribute : HandlerAttribute
{
    public override ICallHandler CreateHandler(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        return new HelloWorldCallHandler();
    }
}

public class HelloWorldCallHandler : ICallHandler
{
    public IMethodReturn Invoke(IMethodInvocation input, GetNextHandlerDelegate getNext)
    {
        Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopwatch.Start();

        //В этом месте происходит вызов метода, помеченного атрибутом
        //либо любого метода класса, если класс целиком помечен
        var result = getNext()(input, getNext);

        stopwatch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(stopwatch.Elapsed);

        return result;
    }

    public int Order { get; set; }
}
```

Ну и регистрируем все это дело в IoC контейнере

```
IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
        container
            .AddNewExtension<Interception>()
            .Configure<Interception>()
            .SetDefaultInterceptorFor<SomeService1>(new TransparentProxyInterceptor());

        var s = container.Resolve<SomeService1>();
        s.Method1();
```

Теперь, при вызове методов класса через контейнер, можно это отследить. Проблема в том, что нужны будут теперь ссылки на контейнер или объект, что в нем лежит.

Answer (score 1):

Только счетчиком.

Однако, чтобы не уродовать свой класс, вы можете его задекорировать его другим классом-оберткой.

Этот класс будет переправлять вызовы к вашему основному классу, но перед этим будет вести какой-то подсчет.

Answer (score 0):

Если эту работу с бд можно реализовать через Singleton, то мне пришел в голову такой хак)

```
public sealed class Worker
{
    private static readonly Lazy<Worker> lazy = new Lazy<Worker>(() => new Worker());
    private static int counter;

    public static Worker Instance
    {
        get
        {
            counter++;
            return lazy.Value;
        }
    }

    public void MegaMethod(){}

    public void SuperMethod(){}

    public int GetMethodCounter()
    {
        return counter;
    }
}
```

Соответственно вот так будет работать:

```
Worker.Instance.MegaMethod();
Worker.Instance.SuperMethod();
int count = Worker.Instance.GetMethodCounter();
```

Однако если обращаться так, то не будет :(

```
var worker = Worker.Instance;
worker.MegaMethod();
worker.SuperMethod();
int count = worker.GetMethodCounter());
```